# MS VS 2010 srand() not compiling?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, srand

I have a piece of code ( I'm student ) that "should" work in theory, but Microsoft's Visual Studio 2010 seems to have a problem with srand, because it's not being highlighted like other reserved names.

If I remove srand from `Auto_Complete_Matrix` then code will compile with no problem.

Function Auto_Complete_Matrix

Error   2   error C2143: error de sintaxis : missing ';' ahead of 'type'    c:\users\jorgee!\desktop\uade\program. 1\proyectos\tp3-matrices\ejercicio 2\main.c  46  1   Ejercicio 2

I've included stdlib and time libraries.

Thanks a lot for the help.

```
/* 2.   Realizar una función que determine si una matriz cuadrada de dimensión N 
es simétrica con respecto a su diagonal principal. */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FIL 5
#define COL 5

int True_False( char *message );
int Auto_Complete_Matrix( int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ] );
int Manual_Complete_Matrix( int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ] );
void Print_Matrix( int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ] );

int main () {
    int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ];
    if( True_False( "Desea autocompletar la Matriz con números al azar? <Si / No> \n\n" ) ) {
        Auto_Complete_Matrix( matrix );
    }
    else {
        Manual_Complete_Matrix( matrix );
    }
    Print_Matrix( matrix );
    system( "pause" );
}

int True_False( char *message ) {
    char Answer[3];
    fputs( message, stdout );
    fgets( Answer, 3, stdin );
    if ( Answer[0] == 1 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ( strncmp( Answer, "Si", 2 ) == 0 || strncmp( Answer, "si", 2 ) ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int Auto_Complete_Matrix ( int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ] ) {

    srand(time(0));
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < FIL; i ++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COL; j ++ ) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % (100 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int Manual_Complete_Matrix( int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ] ) {

    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < FIL; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < COL; j++ ) {
            while( fscanf( stdin, "%d", matrix[i][j] ) != 1 ) {
                fflush( stdin );
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Print_Matrix( int matrix[ FIL ][ COL ] ) {
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < FIL; i++) {
        for( j = 0; j < COL; j++ ) {
            printf( "%5d", matrix[i][j] );
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a file compiled as C (instead of C++), you must declare all variables at the top of the enclosing scope (i.e. in this case the surrounding curly braces).  Here, you're calling a function (srand) before the 'int i, j' declaration statement.

Comment: Damn noob error... I knew it but for some reason I forgot it with srand.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jorge It's hard to tell in the print-out above, but if you look at the line number mentioned by the error, I'd hope it indicates an issue with the variable declaration line, not the srand call line.  Carefully looking at details like those in the error messages will be helpful to you in the long run :)